# Find the area of ​region ABC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In figure $T$ and $K$ are points of tangency,
$MT = a$ and $KN = b$; calculate area of ​​region $ABC$.

(Answer:$2\sqrt{ab}(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2$)

[image]

My progress:

$$S_{ABC} = p \cdot r = \frac{r \cdot (AB+BC+AC)}{2}\\
AC +2R = AB+BC\\
S_{ABC} = AG \cdot GC \qquad \text{(property)} \\
S_{ABC} = (AC+R)R \qquad \text{(property)} \\
OTBQ:~\text{square} \implies TK = R\sqrt2 \\
\ldots ?$$

[image]
I'm not able to use segments a and b in the resolution

Comment: Do we have $\angle ABC=90^\circ$, or equivalently: $CA$ is the diameter of the circumcircle? It would be really helpful to have the whole problem statement, i.e.: "Let $\triangle ABC$ be a (right?) triangle, such that..."

Comment: I think there are a lot of good properties in this problem but I do not how to prove it...such as $M$ and $N$ are actually the middle point of arc$AB$ and arc$BC$, $\angle MGN = \pi/2$, and $MGFN$, $AMTG$, $KGCN$ are three groups of co-circle points. I believe they are right and in fact they can be proved by each other, but I do not know where to start...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva It seems obvious: $AC$ is the diameter of a semicircle and $B$ is any point on that semicircle. Everything else follows. I do agree that this should be explicitly stated.

Comment: I don't see the question in the statement...

Comment: $M $and $N$ are any points. $B$ is  right triangle and $AC$ is diameter...$F$ is center

Comment: @Flagged   all that remains is to find $R$ in function and $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Zieac you are right about $M$ and $N$ being midpoints of the arcs on both sides. Please see my answer.

Comment: @petaarantes I have posted a solution without much algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I continue your process and we already have $\text{TK}=\sqrt{2} R$.

According to intersecting chords theorem, we have  $$\text{AT} \cdot\text{TB}=\text{MT}\cdot \text{TN}$$$$\text{BK} \cdot\text{KC}=\text{KN} \cdot \text{MK}$$
So $$\text{AT}=\sqrt{2} a+\frac{\text{ab}}{R}$$$$\text{KC}=\sqrt{2} b+\frac{\text{ab}}{R}$$
Because $S_{ABC}$ is a rectangular triangle, we have $\text{AB}^2+\text{BC}^2=\text{AC}^2$
and $$\text{BC}=\text{BC}+\text{KC}=\text{KC}+R$$$$ \text{AB}=\text{AT}+\text{TB}=\text{AT}+R$$$$\text{AC}=\text{AG}+\text{GC}=\text{AT}+\text{KC}$$
So solving the equation we get $$R=\sqrt{\text{ab}}$$
Therefore $$S_{ABC} =  \frac{\text{AB}\cdot \text{BC}}{2}$$$$=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2} a+2 \sqrt{\text{ab}}\right) \left(\sqrt{2} b+2 \sqrt{\text{ab}}\right)$$$$=\boxed{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\text{ab}} (a+b)+3 a b}$$
I think the answer you give might be wrong.

Comment: I get same answer as yours. I think you provide correct answer.

Comment: yeah  I have used a geometry software to verify my answer

Comment: thanks for solution.probably..there are a lot of answer errors in this book

Comment: you may want to see my alternate solution without much algebra

Answer (score 5):

Here is a geometrical solution without much algebra.

For a right triangle, if you draw a line through the points of tangency of the incircle with the perpendicular sides, it does bisect the arcs of the circumcircle on both sides. In other words, $M$ and $N$ are  midpoints of minor arcs $AB$ and $BC$ respectively. At the end of the answer, I have shown a proof.

With that, note that $\triangle BTM \sim \triangle NKB$. That leads to,

$\frac{r}{a} = \frac{b}{r} \implies r = \sqrt{ab}$

As $FM$ is perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $FN$ is perpendicular bisector of $BC$,

$\frac{AB}{2} = \sqrt{ab} + \frac{a}{\sqrt2}$ and $\frac{BC}{2} = \sqrt{ab} + \frac{b}{\sqrt2}$

As we know $AB$ and $BC$ in terms of $a$ and $b$, we are done, for $S_{\triangle ABC} = \frac 12 \cdot AB \cdot BC$.

---

Proof of the property that I used in the above answer -

[image]

Say $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of the arcs $AB$ and $BC$ and segment $MN$ intersects $AB$ and $BC$ at $T$ and $K$ respectively.

$\angle BIN = 45^\circ + \angle A/2$
So, $\angle KPN = 90^\circ + \angle A/2$
Also, $\angle PNK = \angle C/2$

That leads to $\angle BKM = \angle PKN = 45^\circ$

Also note that $\angle INK = \angle ICK = \angle C / 2$ so $ICNK$ is cyclic and therefore $\angle KIN = \angle KCN = \angle A / 2$

That leads to $\angle IKM = \angle A / 2 + \angle C / 2 = 45^\circ$

$\angle BKI = \angle BKM + \angle IKM = 90^\circ$.

So $K$ must be point of tangency of incircle with side $BC$. Finally since $KI \parallel BT$ and $BT = BK = KI$, $T$ is the point of tangency of incircle with side $AB$.

Comment: grateful for the resolution.excellent

Comment: Indeed very nice!

Comment: @Dr.Mathva thank you. In fact all three answers are nice in their own way. By the way, you are not to be seen much nowadays. I guess life is busy.

Comment: Hi, @MathLover ... nice answer. What did you use in "*as $FM$ is perp. bisector... $AB/2=$.....*"? Happy New Year ! btw : )

Comment: @ACB good to see you here again. Very happy new year!

Comment: As $BI$ is angle bisector of $\angle B$, $BT = TI = r = \sqrt{ab}$. Also perp from $M$ will meet midpoint of $AB$, say at $Q$ then $TQ = \frac{a}{\sqrt2}$ because $\angle MTQ = 45^\circ$. So $BQ = AB/2 = \sqrt{ab} + a / \sqrt2$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*. Use Power of a point in combination with well-known metric relations of $\triangle ABC$ with regard to the incircle and its contacts points.

I will denote your segments $a$, $b$ with $x,y$ respectively, and will let $a,b,c$ for the side lengths of $\triangle ABC$, as usual. Also, let $s=\frac12(a+b+c)$ denote the semiperimeter of $\triangle ABC$. Using Power of a point

> $$\begin{align*}AT\cdot TB=MT\cdot TN&\iff (s-a)(s-b)=x\cdot (\sqrt2\cdot(s-b)+y)\\BK\cdot KC=MK\cdot KN&\iff (s-b)(s-c)=(x+\sqrt{2}\cdot (s-b))\cdot y\end{align*}$$

I will let you fill in the missing details. Now, you have two equations, where you can solve for $x,y$ in terms of $a,b,c$ (notice: you might want to solve for $x+y, xy$ instead). Finally, what you want to prove is

> $$ac=4\sqrt{xy}\cdot (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2$$

Comment: There was probably an error in the template

Comment: @petaarantes i don't really understand what you're saying?

Comment: Sorry..I thought you posted your answer...as the area = $ac=4\sqrt{xy}\cdot (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2$ but now I understand...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva you may want to see my alternate solution